# Width/height as auto value forced as percentage?

Tags: html, css

if i have an element where width and height is sat to auto, can i force it to auto as em / percent in css ?

The reason for this is because pixel decimal values are not respected by the browser and will be rounded up/down.

Answer (score 3):

Any length value, regardless of its specified unit, will resolve to a used value in pixels. Even if you could change the behavior of `auto` — which you can't — you'd still end up with a pixel used value.

Rounding inconsistencies are an unfortunate consequence of divergent implementations. There is not much you can do about it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set the width or height of an element to a percentage.

In your CSS it would be:

height: 50%;

Comment: what i want is the width : auto to generate a % value instead of pixel value. Not to set the width to a specific value such as 50.

Comment: With width: 50% it will only take up 50 percent of the space and not be set to a pixel value. So if the screen size gets increased, the element would automatically increase with it.